# ROSJava messages missing "callerid" field

Tags: actionlib, rosjava, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been running rosjava nodes on my PC and connecting them to rospy and roscpp nodes on the same PC. I can get publish and subscribe of basic messages to work fine. However, if I try to publish tf's or use actionlib_java, I get errors revolving around missing callerids.

The following is an example of this issue using the actionlib_java sample Fibonacci server and the actionlib_tutorial sample (python) Fibonacci client:

I got the ROSJava example Actionlib server (/org.ros.actionlib_java/src/tutorials/java/org/ros/actionlib/example/RunFibonacciSimpleActionServer.java) to connect to the python actionlib client (ros/common_tutorials/actionlib_tutorials/simple_action_clients/fibonacci_client.py) provided in ROS electric, but I get callerid errors.

To get this to run, I first noticed that running RunFibonacciSimpleActionServer.java failed with

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Node name not specified.
        at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:204)
        at org.ros.node.DefaultNodeRunner.run(DefaultNodeRunner.java:85)
        at org.ros.node.DefaultNodeRunner.run(DefaultNodeRunner.java:110)
        at org.ros.actionlib.example.RunFibonacciSimpleActionServer.main(RunFibonacciSimpleActionServer.java:31)
        at org.ros.actionlib.example.RunFibonacciSimpleActionServer.main(RunFibonacciSimpleActionServer.java:15)
```

So, on line 28 of RunFibonacciSimpleActionServer.java, I added a name to the node

```
configuration.setNodeName("fibonacci_server_node");
```

Then it runs, but does not connect. If I look at rxgraph (with all topics turned on), I see that where the rospy client is looking for the action messages (status, result, feedback, etc) in the /fibonacci namespace, the ROSJava server is broadcasting in the global namespace (i.e., without a namespace). To get these to connect, I remapped the rospy client's topics into the global namespace using the following launch file:

```
<launch>
  <node name="fibonacci_client" pkg="actionlib_tutorials" type="fibonacci_client.py">
    <remap from="/fibonacci/goal" to="/goal" />
    <remap from="/fibonacci/cancel" to="/cancel" />
    <remap from="/fibonacci/feedback" to="/feedback" />
    <remap from="/fibonacci/status" to="/status" />
    <remap from="/fibonacci/result" to="/result" />
  </node>
</launch>
```

Now the nodes connect, but the rospy node crashes with the following error:

```
process[fibonacci_client-2]: started with pid [11301]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/other/ros/common_tutorials/actionlib_tutorials/simple_action_clients/fibonacci_client.py", line 66, in <module>
    result = fibonacci_client()
  File "/other/ros/common_tutorials/actionlib_tutorials/simple_action_clients/fibonacci_client.py", line 47, in fibonacci_client
    client.wait_for_server()
  File "/other/ros/common/actionlib/src/actionlib/simple_action_client.py", line 68, in wait_for_server
    return self.action_client.wait_for_server(timeout)
  File "/other/ros/common/actionlib/src/actionlib/action_client.py", line 577, in wait_for_server
    server_id = self.last_status_msg._connection_header['callerid']
KeyError: 'callerid'
[fibonacci_client-2] process has died [pid 11301, exit code 1].
```

It seems to be missing the "callerid" attribute.

As an aside, I've seen the same problem when I publish tf's from a rosjava node and receive them with a roscpp node. In particular, libtf within the roscpp node gets angry that the callerid is missing from the tf's it receives. If I "roswtf" the setup, I'll see that the rosjava nodes appear as two different nodes: one with the correct node name (e.g., tf_publisher) but not connected to any other nodes and one with the IP (eg, 127.0.0.1) for the node name and connected to the correct nodes. I think callerid may be the node name tracked by the master.  Maybe my rosjava nodes are not registering their node name with the ROS master correctly?

Thanks for any help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12219/rosjava-messages-missing-%22callerid%22-field-/) by [shawn3](https://answers.ros.org/users/1485/shawn3/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-12-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the "missing callerid" warning issued in c++ when I instantiated tfMessages from a bagfile and published it (not via the tf broadcaster but a regular publisher). Since the warnings were quite annoying I tried to fix it, but couldn't find much information except [this](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Connection%20Header).

For roscpp I fixed this not really quick but hopefully not too dirty by manually setting `msg->__connection_header["caller_id"] = "name_of_my_node"`, but I am not sure whether this is a good way to go.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2011-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-12-12**:
There's a related ticket here http://code.google.com/p/rosjava/issues/detail?id=15

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2011-12-06**:
Optimally, you could trace down the place in the publisher code of rosjava, fix it there and submit a patch :-)

**Comment by [shawn3](https://answers.ros.org/users/1485/shawn3/) on 2011-12-06**:
Thanks for the info. It doesn't seem that ROSJava gives me access to this field in the outgoing messages (on the publication side). I could try catching messages on the subscriber side and fixing them up, but that's only a bandaid.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This should be fixed at head.

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-01-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1